# SQL Query Help on Conditions

Tags: sql, case

I have a table A with columns as below:

```
Addr_id   Street_Add      Addr_type_cd        Acct_nbr         CITY                     
   1        12 ST             PROP               A              MN
   1        12 ST             MAIL               A1             MN
   1        12 ST             PROP               B              MN
   1        12 ST             PROP               A              MN
   1        12 ST             PROP               A              MN
   2        13 ST             PROP               A2             MI
   2        13 ST             MAIL               A3             MI
   3        14 ST             PROP               AB             MO
   4        15 ST             MAIL               AD             IL
```

Output is as below;

```
OUTPUT - ADDR_ID            OUTPUT - ADDR_TYPE_ CD          
    1      PROP         
    1      MAIL         
    1      RPT          
    2      PROP         
    2      MAIL         
    2      RPT          
    3      PROP         
    3      RPT          
    4      MAIL         
    4      RPT
```

The natural key is Street_addr and CITY. I am trying to write a Case expression populating another column ADDR_TYPE_CD in Table B based on below rules

> - WHERE STREET_ADD=STREET_ADD and CITY=CITY
> - IF ADDR_TYPE_cd= PROP and MAIL,
> - THEN ADDR_TYPE_CD in TABLE B = PROP, MAIL, RPT
> - IF ADDR_TYPE_cd= PROP
> - THEN ADDR_TYPE_CD in TABLE B = PROP, RPT
> - IF ADDR_TYPE_cd= MAIL
> - THEN ADDR_TYPE_CD in TABLE B = MAIL, RPT

I have tried writing through CASE statement as :

```
SELECT
     CASE addr_type_cd
     WHEN addr_type_cd='PROP' AND addr_type_cd='MAIL'                               
     THEN addr_type_cd='RPT' AND addr_type_cd='PROP' AND addr_type_cd='MAIL'    
     END                        
FROM Table A                        
WHERE street_addr = street_addr                     
AND city = city
```

I get missing keyword error, plus am not sure if the logic would work. Any inputs ideas will be very helpful. Hope the question is clear.

Thanks,

Pallavi

Comment: Sorry. I couldnt add Image with table format correctly

Comment: You can't assign multiple column values within a single CASE test like you're attempting. The THEN portion of your statement simply won't work. You can at best output a single aliased column. I can't offer a suggestion as to how to fix it, because I find your explanation of what you're trying to do rather confusing. How can `street_addr` **NOT** equal `street_addr` or ` `city` **NOT** equal `city` when they're the same column in the same row? IOW, your logic as written will **always** return every single row, because the columns will **always** be equal.

Answer (score 0):

There are few problems,

1. *your are trying to insert multiple rows into Target table based on single row in source table, if Addr_type_cd = 'PROP' insert two rows one with 'Prop' and another with 'RPT'*
2. *Same way you are trying to capture data from two rows at same time and insert according to that, if prop, mail insert prop,mail,rpt*

What you should do is fix your source Column `(Addr_type_cd)` to have grouped values where needed. After that it is simple.
If source was like below, I have pasted corresponding code:

[image: Table_A_Modified]

```
Insert into Table_B
(   
    [Addr_id], 
    [Street_Add],
    [Addr_type_cd],
    [Acct_nbr] ,
    [CITY]
)
Select
    [Addr_id], 
    [Street_Add],        
        CASE 
            WHEN addr_type_cd = 'PROP' THEN 'PROP;RPT'   
            WHEN addr_type_cd='MAIL' THEN 'MAIL;RPT'    
            WHEN addr_type_cd='PROP;MAIL' THEN 'PROP;MAIL;RPT'
        END ,
    [Acct_nbr] ,
    [CITY]  
From Table_A
```